# Alpha channel is acting and outputting green in directx11 and c++

Tags: c++, colors, shader, directx-11, lighting

I am new to Directx11 .I wanted to create point Light behaviour to my program.So I defined a struct like so

```
struct PointLights
{

    XMFLOAT3 Pos; //Light Position in (X,Y,Z)
    float Range; //the range after which objects will not be affected by this light
    XMFLOAT4 Color;  //Light Color
    XMFLOAT3 att; // Attenuation Parameters
    float Intensity;

};
```

And Added it to constant buffer like

```
struct ConstantBuffer
{

 XMMATRIX World;
 XMMATRIX WorldInv;
 XMMATRIX View;
 XMMATRIX Project;

 XMFLOAT3 LighDirs[2];
 XMFLOAT4 LightColor[2];
 float SpecualrIntensity;
 XMFLOAT3 CameraPos;
 PointLights pointLight;

};
```

This function is used to create buffer

```
void InitConstantBuffer(void)
{
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc;
    SecureZeroMemory(&desc,sizeof(desc));

    desc.BindFlags= D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer);
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    SecureZeroMemory(&g_ConstantBuffer,sizeof(ID3D11Buffer));

HRESULT HR= dev->CreateBuffer(&desc,0,&g_ConstantBuffer);
if(FAILED(HR))
    MessageBox(_hwnd,L"Couldnt Create constant buffer",L"ERROR",0);

}
```

Now When i update the point lights color to black but set its alpha to 1 (0,0,0,1)
the out put is green and output is black if alpha is 0 (0,0,0,0)

```
PointLights pointLight;

    SecureZeroMemory(&pointLight,sizeof(PointLights));
    pointLight.att = XMFLOAT3(0,0,1);

    pointLight.Intensity = 5;
    pointLight.Pos = XMFLOAT3(Lppos[0],Lppos[1],Lppos[2]);
    pointLight.Range = 200;
    pointLight.Color = XMFLOAT4(0,0,0,1); // black

    ConstantBuffer cb;
    cb.World = XMMatrixTranspose(g_World);
    cb.View = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
    cb.Project = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
    cb.WorldInv  = InverseTranspose(g_World);
    cb.LighDirs[1] = lights[1].Dir;
    cb.LightColor[1] = lights[1].Color;

    cb.LightColor[0] = lights[0].Color;cb.LighDirs[0] = lights[0].Dir;
    cb.LightColor[0] = lights[0].Color;
    cb.SpecualrIntensity = 10;
    cb.CameraPos = XMFLOAT3(0,0,-10);
    cb.pointLight = pointLight;


    devcon->UpdateSubresource(g_ConstantBuffer,0,0,&cb,0,0);
```

![output is green][1]

*Cant upload image as stackoverflow wont let me...I hate it*

Here is hte pixel shader

```
struct PointLights{
    float3 Position;
    float Range;
    float4 Color;
    float3 Atten;
    float Intensity;
};

cbuffer ConstantBuffer:register(b0)
{
 matrix world;
 matrix worldInv;
 matrix view;
 matrix project;

 float3 LightDir[2];
 float4 LightColor[2];
 float SpecualrIntensity;
 float3 CameraPos;

 PointLights pointLight;

};

float4 Ps(Vout vo):SV_TARGET
{
 float4 col = (float4)0;
 col = pointLight.Color;
return col;}
```

Please do help me out.. I tried rearranging the members of struct but still in vain

Thanks ....

Comment: You are using ``XMMATRIX`` in the struct ConstantBuffer. This _might_ work, it _might_ not, depending on exactly how you are using it. It makes ``ConstantBuffer`` require 16-byte alignement in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite likely that the data alignment between the C++ constant buffer structures and HLSL cbuffer declarations do not quite match. Try using `XMFLOAT4` instead of `XMFLOAT3` to ensure they line up the same way in both.

You are using `XMMATRIX` in `struct ConstantBuffer`. This *might* work, it *might* not, depending on exactly how you are using it. It makes `ConstantBuffer` require 16-byte alignement in memory. If you are making this assumption, use `XMVECTOR` rather then `XMFLOAT3` or `XMFLOAT4`. Otherwise, change `XMMATRIX` to `XMMFLOAT4X4`.

If you find the DirectXMath alignment thing confusing, consider using the [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) wrapper from [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).

Comment: hi It worked after using XMVECTOR insted of XMFLOAT4 .. Can you please explain to me why this happens .. And Can i use D3DXVECTOR3 instead .. Thanks

Comment: XMVECTOR forces 16-byte alignment, so that probably changed the layout of the struct to match the HLSL cbuffer. I expect it would've also worked if you had used ``XMFLOAT4A``. The problem is that that ``float3 lightDir[2];`` uses different number of bytes in memory than ``XMFLOAT3 LighDirs[2];`` because HLSL ensures that no individual element crosses a 16-byte boundary. See [Packing Rules for Constant Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: You shouldn't use the [legacy D3DX math library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for a number of reasons--although you can if you really wanted to. If you find DirectXMath overwhelming, SimpleMath is the way to go.